# Android View onResume method?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

When returning to an activity using the back button and

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMainMenu.class));
```

is called, are there any methods that automatically go to a custom view?

I've noticed that when going back to the view, it's no longer invalidated.

Basically without using the activity's onResume I want to be able to resume my custom view.

Comment: That's where you want to use Fragments. (they are tied to the lifecycle.)

Comment: Because I'm creating custom views with animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who wants to know you can use:

```
protected void onAttachedToWindow()
```

It's called every time a view is attached to the Window.

Comment: Does not get called when resuming app from background

Answer (score 0):

In the [Android Source for TextView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3585-L3593), it `post`s a `Runnable`.

```
    if (ss.error != null) {
        final CharSequence error = ss.error;
        // Display the error later, after the first layout pass
        post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setError(error);
            }
        });
    }
```